# How to recover the suspect mode database in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

To recover the database from suspect mode executes the following query.

```
EXEC sp_resetstatus ‘yourDBname’;
ALTER DATABASE yourDBname SET EMERGENCY
DBCC checkdb(’yourDBname’)
ALTER DATABASE yourDBname SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
DBCC CheckDB (’yourDBname’, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
ALTER DATABASE yourDBname SET MULTI_USER
```

Then getting

> Check terminated. A failure was detected while collecting facts.
>   Possibly tempdb out of space or a system table is inconsistent. Check
>   previous errors

How to resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server 2008 database is suspected](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16226/sql-server-2008-database-is-suspected). Even though this question is one month elder, the other one has better answers.

Answer (score 1):

According to Paul Randal, this seems to be a bug in checkdb. Check [this article](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/CHECKDB-bug-that-people-are-hitting-Msg-8967-Level-16-State-216.aspx) from Paul which discusses about this issue.

The workaround is to run `CHECKDB` on the database with `TABLOCK`

Answer (score 0):

Run DBCC CHECKDB without the repair option.  What does it tell you?  If the system tables are corrupt then it's game over and time to restore from backup.

Answer (score -1):

You have a database in MS SQL that is tagged as (suspect) and you are unable to connect to the database.

**Possible Causes**

- The database could have become corrupted.

  There is not enough space available for the SQL Server to recover the
  database during startup.

  The database cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or
  insufficient memory or disk space.

  The database files are being held by operating system, third party
  backup software etc.

  There was an unexpected SQL Server Shutdown, power failure or a
  hardware failure.

**Solution**

Open Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and connect to your database

Click the New Query button

Paste the following SQL script into your New Query page replacing [YourDatabase] with the name of your database.

```
EXEC sp_resetstatus [YourDatabase];
ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabase] SET EMERGENCY
DBCC checkdb([YourDatabase])
ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabase] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
DBCC CheckDB ([YourDatabase], REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabase] SET MULTI_USER
Click Execute
```

Source : https://support.appzone.com/kb/a398/how-to-repair-a-suspect-database-in-mssql.aspx

Answer (score -1):

If Process Deadlock occurs, use this command below:

SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH ALTER DATABASE dbname SET MULTI_USER;